# Flask MongoAlchemy with multi hosts urls

Tags: python, flask, mongoalchemy

I am new on MongoAlchemy. Currently i have pymongo which i only need use 1 URL to connect to mongolabs server

> mongodb://myusername:secretpassword@ds045801-a1.mongolab.com:45801,ds045808-a0.mongolab.com:45808/mydatabase_name

While MongoAlchemy use MONGOALCHEMY_SERVER but it seems only take 1 host.
Is there anyway to use the whole url as connection string?
e.g

```
app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_SERVER'] =  'mongodb://myusername:secretpassword@ds045801-a1.mongolab.com:45801,ds045808-a0.mongolab.com:45808/mydatabase_name'
```

Cheers

Comment: Is this to connect to a replica set?

Comment: Yeah i suppose it is a replica since mongolabs provides master and slave nodes.

Comment: It should work out what is in the replica set for you

Comment: No it doesn't work. If you read the source code it takes only 1 server. Return will then merge the host,port as string...

Comment: It should be a PyMongo thing http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/high_availability.html#id1

Comment: We use pymongo in previous projects but this time is Flask-MongoAlchemy, which you cannot add multiply hosts in the app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_SERVER']. It uses _get_mongo_uri and `return with uri = 'mongodb://%s%s:%s/%s%s' % (auth, app.config.get(key('SERVER')),
                                      app.config.get(key('PORT')), database, options)`

Comment: Sorry I miss read I thought you were on about Pymongo. Look here https://github.com/cobrateam/flask-mongoalchemy/blob/master/flask_mongoalchemy/__init__.py#L101. There is a REPLICA_SET option but that is not what you are after. I guess send them a pull request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**
If anyone have same issue, version 0.7.1 is now support with connection string:
https://github.com/cobrateam/flask-mongoalchemy/issues/40

---

I think i found a away to pass 2 hosts. Since the _get_mongo_uri expects

`mongodb://%s%s:%s/%s%s' % (auth, app.config.get(key('SERVER')),
                                      app.config.get(key('PORT')), database, options)`

I just insert the

mongodb://myusername:secretpassword@**ds045801-a1.mongolab.com:45801,ds045808-a0.mongolab.com**:45808/mydatabase_name

And the result is:
`app.config['MONGOALCHEMY_SERVER'] = "ds045801-a1.mongolab.com:45801,ds045808-a0.mongolab.com"`

It's a bit ugly but it works (for now)

The mongodb connection string format is like this

mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/